# Dealing with Redirection Operator with User Input

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

To get a complete Log Output of a particular Batch Script, I have been using the `2>&1`, but in some of my batch script need to have the user input also (i.e.- yes/no), in that case how could I have the complete Log Output of the specific Batch Job?

Comment: `set /p var=prompt text` and echo `%var%>file.txt`

Comment: @KlausPrinoth, the question was tagged with `batch-file`. That is a Windows .bat script.  Your code will not work in a Windows environment.

Comment: Hello Klaus, thanks for your reply, but I am not using `PowerShell`. Will it be applicable in simple `DOS` ?

Comment: Edit your question and share your code to get helped !

Comment: That's very simple, let's say just `test -t` for the process Test.exe.

Answer (score 0):

**NB :** Next time provide us your code to get more helped !

Try Something like that :

```
@echo off
set /p var=prompt text
echo %var% >log.txt 2>&1

set process=Test.exe,test2.exe,calc.exe,skype.exe
For %%a in (%process%) Do Call :KillMyProcess %%a
pause
Exit /b

:KillMyProcess
Taskkill /IM "%~1" /F >> log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks V for your reply, but where will I call my `command/script`, which is related to any of the process (i.e.-Test.exe,test2.exe,calc.exe,skype.exe) .....?